# Any way to set the z-order when using MigLayout and absolute positioning?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout, z-order

I'm using MigLayout and absolute positioning to overlay a busy indicator on a panel. Sometimes the indicator appears behind the panel, sometimes in front. Is there any way to specify the z-order to ensure that the indicator always appears in front?

I saw in a post that "z-order is not up to the layout manager". If this is the case, who is it up to and can it be controlled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call [`container.setComponentZOrder(component, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) however there are some extra rules regarding [heavy vs light components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/).